# One section of the view controller is still and one section horizontally scrollable

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to construct a view controller where one section of the view controller would be still and one section scrollable.

Both sections have headers where as well, one is still and one is moving along with the content in the section.

I do not want the cells in the section to be scrolled separately. All cells should move at the same time along with the header.

I have added an image to make my point little more clearer.

[image: An example]

Comment: Check this 3rd party library TSTableView. Its a tableView which has similarity to the working you mentioned. Link: https://github.com/Viacheslav-Radchenko/TSTableView

Answer (score 0):

Use UICollection View for both view and disable scrolling for one view and enable scrolling for another view

Answer (score 0):

you can probably add to your `UIViewController` view a `UITableView` on the left with fixed size (for example 150px) and vertical scroll disabled and a `UICollectionView` with horizontal flow and ,if needed a, with custom `UICollectionViewLayout` (but i think that you just need the classic `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`) for the right part that fits the remaining space.

Here you can find the component's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview